# Pycharm expected type 'optional[bytes]' got 'str' instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, pycharm

I am using `rsplit` to split up a path name,

```
rootPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
rootPath = (rootPath.rsplit('/', 1)[0]).rsplit('/', 1)[0]
```

But **Pycharm** warns,

> expected type `optional [bytes]`, got `str` instead

In `python doc`, it stated *using `sep` as the delimiter string*.

So how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems like `rootPath` is being treated as a bytes object (a small bug maybe?) or the warning is for another part.

In general, what PyCharm and the error is essentially warning you about is that the parameter has to either be `None` or `bytes`. That's  what [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) means, `Optional[type]` is either `None` or `type` which in your case is `bytes`.

In a simple Python REPL the message is slightly different but the gist is the same:

```
b'hello/world'.rsplit('/') # error bytes-like object required
```

Instead you need to supply a `byte` separator:

```
b'hello/world'.rsplit(b'/')
```

or `None` in order to get it to work.

Either there's a small bug in PyCharm and it's reporting `rsplit` incorrectly here or the warning is for another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem and found a slightly different solution - thought of adding it for anyone that may land into the same issue in future.

```
rootPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
rootPath = str(rootPath.rsplit('/', 1)[0]).rsplit('/', 1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this earlier:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    "ls /etc/systemd/system",
    shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True
)

for line in result.stdout.split("\n"):
    if "banana" in line:
        print(line.split(".")[0].strip().split("_"))
```

PyCharm began highlighting: "\n", "banana", ".", "_":

[image: PyCharm flagging strings as wrong]

It says it expects `Optional[bytes]` or `Union[bytes,int]`, and yet this code runs perfectly well in python 3.10, 3.9, and 3.8.

I suspected it was my recent selection of Settings->Editor->Inspections->Code compatibility inspection so I disabled it and restarted that window to no avail.

I have added `.decode()` after `.stdout` to convert bytes. That quietens PyCharm, but is noise upon noise. In python 3.10 `.stdout` is not `bytes` but `str` and I'd get an error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.

In the python docs I find the same method names in [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split) that I do in [str](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)