# Python Pandas Multiindex names warning

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm creating multi-level columns for dataframes:

```
lst_of_tuples = [('A', 'X'), ('A', 'Y'), ('B', 'X'), ('B', 'Y')]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lst_of_tuples, names=[None, None])
```

Which seems to match [the documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), example below (though I'm building multi-level columns, not an index):

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
```

and I'm getting a warning from PyCharm about an expected type, specifically on the "names" variable:

> Expected type 'Optional[Sequence[Hashable]]', got 'list[None]' instead

I'm getting the results I wanted, but I'd love to clear this warning up anyway. I'm not sure what type of object should be entered here, since the documentation seems clear. Is this a PyCharm bug? Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

create a dataframe using multiIndex.from_tubles for the columns.  The columns include the one to many parent child relationship

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                      [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('d', 'b')],name=['first','second']))
```

output

```
 first   a     d
 second  b  c  b
 0       1  2  3
 1       4  5  6
 2       7  8  9
```

Comment: it must be a problem with pycharm because python 3.8 works

Comment: what PyCharm and the error is essentially warning you about is that the parameter has to either be None or Sequence[Hash]   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447741/pycharm-expected-type-optionalbytes-got-str-instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python  Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.  Therefore, none must not be hashable